# select if exsists else insert and select

Tags: java, mysql

Ok, I'm using Java with MySQL and I was wondering how can I make SELECT the userId if it exists, or INSERT it in the table before selecting the assigned userId, which is an AUTO_INCREMENT value.

I have this code:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO `player_id`(`name`) VALUES('exInput')";
Statement statment = Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS; 
PreparedStatement pstmt = MySQLUtil.getConnection().prepareStatement(query, statment);  
ResultSet keys = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
keys.next();
int userId = keys.getInt(1);
```

Which works fine when the input isn't on the table, but I need it to work even if it's already on the table.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: 'cause I need to make sure that the player is on the table and get his ID, and I got do this in the fastest and reliable way

Comment: But are you sure you need check first ? Why not simply run an insert or an INSERT...SELECT? This would be faster

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps ?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT <id> FROM <table> WHERE <id>='some_id') 
    BEGIN
        SELECT <id> FROM <table> WHERE <id>=''
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO <table>(fieldval) VALUES('')
    END
```

Though you should probably have some indexes then. Otherwise you could do it in to iterations making a select first and if it returns null then do an insert. If you do this however you have to be aware of concurrent requests if that can happen.

Comment: Got that error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM `user_id` WHERE `name`='someName') BEGIN SELECT ' at line 1